# Single query SELECT propagate to childs

Tags: php, sqlite

i have this table structure:

```
id
name
email
child_id <- pointing to id from "child" table
```

how SELECT this table data and propagate select to all childs with a SINGLE QUERY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you assume you're working with a child table with its own name and id field, you could write...

```
select c.name as child_name, p.name as parent_name
from child c
  join parent p
    on c.id = p.child_id
```

I made a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/44dc5/1) with the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "parent" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" TEXT,
    "email" TEXT,
    "child_id" INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE "child" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" TEXT
);

INSERT INTO parent
(id, name, email, child_id )
VALUES
(1, "Jim", "pineapple@fruit.com", 1 ),
(2, "Jane", "gizmo@gadget.com", 1 ),
(3, "Grover", "monty@python.com", 2 );

INSERT INTO child
(id, name)
VALUES
(1, "Ben" ),
(2, "Samantha" ),
(3, "Carl" );
```

My select query then gave me:
[image]

However, this data structure limits you to only on child per parent though I showed 2 parents for one of the kids. If you want multiple of either without having to duplicate the parent entries, you'd want to have a third table for the parent child relationship. That Table would have a parent_id, a child_id, and there are different schools of thought on whether it having it's own id would be required (it makes selecting specific rows in the relationship table easy and becomes more important if the relationship gains additional fields itself). Your query would need to join all the tables to the relationship table and if you did this, that part might look something like this:

```
from relationship r
  join parent p
    on p.relation_id = r.parent_id
  join child c
    on c.relation_id = r.child_id
```

Comment: perfect @palu-macil , and.. how to get a sub array w/ full parent data? something like this:
http://i.imgur.com/mHeB7AU.png

Comment: SQLite doesn't support arrays directly. The way with minimal effort would probably be to add the other parent columns you need to the select and then build the array on the application side. You can put any field in the select with tablename.fieldname from ANY of the tables that were joined. Note that in this case, I replaced the table names with single letter aliases to make it shorter, so I'm actually required to use 'p' instead of parent.You could write something like `select c.name as child_name, p.id as parent_id, p.name as parent_name, p.email`. The AS keyword simply names the column.

Comment: @intrd Actually, you could do something like `select c.name as child, 'array(id=' || p.id || ',name=''' || p.name || ''',email=''' || p.email || ''')' as parent` but I'd be nearly willing to bet that this isn't quite what you're hoping for because it'd be the TEXT you asked for (not an actual query). If you're using PHP, you'll need to loop through your result rows and create the array. Or... the result array might be what you need if you add the other columns. ;) I didn't test this syntax, but double single quotes ('') allow a single quote INSIDE a string, and || concatenates two strings.